# in ARMv6 assembly one code is not working, but the modified version works. Why?

Tags: assembly, arm, armv6

i have a programm in armv6 assembly which calculates the result of (x +y)^2

this code doesn't work, and returns: "Unsupported ARM syscall: 0xffffffdf"

```
.global _start
.text
_start:
    MOV r0, #4
    MOV r1, #5
    MOV r7, #1
    BL calc
    SWI #0

calc:
    ADD r7, r0, r1
    MUL R0, R7, R7
    MOV PC, LR
```

but this one is slightly edited and works (or it doesn't?):

```
.global _start
.text
_start:
   MOV r0, #4
   MOV r1, #5
   MOV r7, #1
   BL calc
   BL exit

calc:
   ADD r7, r0, r1
   MUL R0, R7, R7
   MOV PC, LR

exit:
   LDR r7, =1
   SWI 0
```

can anyone please tell me why the first code is not working?
is the second one even valid?

Comment: What operating system are you programming for?

Comment: What do you think the value of `r7` is throughout the program?

Comment: If this is a Linux system call, then `r7` selects the system call number.  `_exit()` is system call number 1.  Your second code executes `swi 0` with `r7` containing the value 1, so it works.  In the first code, `r7` does not contain 1 when `swi 0` executes, because the `calc` function modified it.

Comment: If this is Linux, run `strace ./a.out` to trace/decode the system calls your code makes, to help you understand Nate's comment.  Oh, you already have an error message about a bad system-call number, but strangely it's showing it as `0xffffffdf` not `9`, the call-number you actually used in R7.

Comment: @PeterCordes 9 is the first system call, `0xffffffdf` is the third system call.

Comment: If this is `qemu-arm` running under linux (as the error message suggests), pass the `-strace` option to trace system calls.

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin: Oh right, after `SWI` returns (with an error code in R0), it loops since execution falls into `exit` with LR still set.

Answer (score 1):

First set `r0` and `r1`:

```
 MOV r0, #4
 MOV r1, #5
```

Setting `r7` here has no effect:

```
 MOV r7, #1
```

Call `calc`:

```
 BL calc

calc:
 ADD r7, r0, r1
 MUL R0, R7, R7
 MOV PC, LR
```

`r7` is now 4 + 5 = 9.

Call system call number 9, which is `link`:

```
 SWI 0
```

`link` requires 2 arguments which are pointers to strings, since neihter 81 nor 5 are valid pointers it returns the error `-EFAULT` = -14 in `r0`.

```
calc:
 ADD r7, r0, r1
 MUL R0, R7, R7
 MOV PC, LR
```

`r7` is now -14 + 5 = -9 = `0xfffffff7`.

Call system call number `0xfffffff7`, which does not exist:

```
 SWI 0
```

The error `-ENOSYS` = -38 is returned in `r0`.

```
calc:
 ADD r7, r0, r1
 MUL R0, R7, R7
 MOV PC, LR
```

`r7` is now -38 + 5 = -33 = `0xffffffdf`.

Call system call number `0xffffffdf`, which does not exist:

```
 SWI 0
```

And this repeats indefinitely.

The correct program sets `r7` to 1 before `SWI 0` so executes the `exit` system call.